# Get instance of aspect at runtime

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm running a command line application that uses annotation based aspect to gather statistics.

Is it possible to retrieve aspect instance to fetch the statistics? Or the only possible way is to keep statistics as `static` variable and get it at desired moment?

```
@Aspect
public class StatisticsAspect {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StatisticsAspect.class);
    private final Statistics statistics;

    public StatisticsAspect() {
        statistics = new Statistics();
    }

    // Some code...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspectJ aspects are by default singletons, i.e. using a static variable (maybe a static `ThreadLocal`, if you store thread-related information) and maybe providing a nice static getter method is a good option. There are other instantiation models, but for them you need to declare the aspect in a different way, something like `@Aspect("perthis(execution(* ajia.Account.*(..)))")`. All in all, there are the instantiation types `perthis()`, `pertarget()`, `percflow()`, `percflowbelow()` and `pertypewithin()`. It is nothing to worry about in your case if your statistics are really global.

As an alternative, you can also keep the statistics in an instance variable, but if it is private like in your case, you also need to provide a getter method for it, something like `public Statistics getStatistics()`. In that case, if you want to get access to an AspectJ-managed singleton aspect instance, you ought to use `Aspects.aspectOf(StatisticsAspect.class)`, see also the [AspectJ manual](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-aspectof.html). Then you would access the data like this:

```java
Aspects.aspectOf(StatisticsAspect.class).getStatistics();
```